# PHP Simple DOM Parser extract single value from two url

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I use dom parser to grab text from two html documents with the same `li` class and I retrieved a double value.

```
<?php 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$links = array (
                "Model_one" => "car.html",
                "Model_two" => "car/edition.html"
            );

foreach ($links as $key=>$link) {
    $html = file_get_html($link);
    $ret[] = $html->find('ul li[class=dotCar]',0)->plaintext;

    $pattern = '/.\d+(?:\.\d{2})?((?<=[0-9])(?= usd))/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $ret[0], $result);

    $price = array();

    foreach($result[0] as $k=>$v) {
        $price[] = $v; 
        echo $price[0];
    }
}

// $price[0]=  10.55  11
?>
```

How can I associate the `model_key` from `$links` array  to value `$price` to obtain the result:

```
model_one 10.55
model_two 11.00
```

In this way I can retrieve the single value to insert in a MySQL table.

Comment: What does `$html->find('ul li[class=dotCar]',0)->plaintext` returns ?

Comment: a string of letters and numbers

Comment: Well, sure I guessed that, please post the exact output in both cases so I can help you reshape the code...

Comment: You need to include the html for questions like this

Comment: @ Enissay, pguardario `code`$html->find('ul li[class=dotCar]',0)->plaintext`code`  return this string "Only 10.95 usd for 2 years,or 150.30 usd. 
Only 11.00 usd for  2 years, or 160.00 usd"

Comment: Part 2 I extract the number 10.95, 150.30  11.00 and 160.00 with regex `code`/.\d+(?:\.\d{2})?((?<=[0-9])(?= usd))/`code`

I'd like to insert single value in mysql table pick every number for the links key:
model_one 10.95
model_one 150.30
model_two 11.00
model_two 160.00

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
foreach($result as $k=>$v) {
//$v is the price (10.55 etc.)
    foreach($links as $kk=>$vv) {
    //$vv is the link (model_one etc.)
        $priceAndLinks[$vv] = $v;
    }
}
```

This might give you an idea of the logic needed.